# dns.name.EmptyLabel: A DNS label is empty. when importing socketio or eventlet

Tags: python, socket.io, dns, conda, eventlet

Project GitHub repo:
https://github.com/EdoardoCocconi/Udacity-Self-Driving-Car-Nanodegree/tree/master/Project%204%20-%20Behavioral%20Cloning

I am working on a conda environment. Everything was working 1 month ago. I came back to make some changes and when I try to import socketio or eventlet I get the error I pasted below. I haven't changed anything in the environment and tried to update flask-socketio, eventlet, and dnspython. I also created a new environment but the error persists:

```
(carnd-term1) D:\OneDrive - The University of Nottingham\Edo\United Kingdom\Udacity\Self-Driving Car Nanodegree\Project 4 - Behavioral Cloning>python drive.py model.h5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "drive.py", line 8, in <module>
    import eventlet.wsgi
  File "C:\Users\Edoardo\miniconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\eventlet\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from eventlet import convenience
  File "C:\Users\Edoardo\miniconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\eventlet\convenience.py", line 7, in <module>
    from eventlet.green import socket
  File "C:\Users\Edoardo\miniconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\eventlet\green\socket.py", line 21, in <module>
    from eventlet.support import greendns
  File "C:\Users\Edoardo\miniconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\eventlet\support\greendns.py", line 399, in <module>
    resolver = ResolverProxy(hosts_resolver=HostsResolver())
  File "C:\Users\Edoardo\miniconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\eventlet\support\greendns.py", line 313, in __init__
    self.clear()
  File "C:\Users\Edoardo\miniconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\eventlet\support\greendns.py", line 316, in clear
    self._resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver(filename=self._filename)
  File "C:\Users\Edoardo\miniconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 543, in __init__
    self.read_registry()
  File "C:\Users\Edoardo\miniconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 720, in read_registry
    self._config_win32_fromkey(key, False)
  File "C:\Users\Edoardo\miniconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 674, in _config_win32_fromkey
    self._config_win32_domain(dom)
  File "C:\Users\Edoardo\miniconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 639, in _config_win32_domain
    self.domain = dns.name.from_text(str(domain))
  File "C:\Users\Edoardo\miniconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\dns\name.py", line 889, in from_text
    return from_unicode(text, origin, idna_codec)
  File "C:\Users\Edoardo\miniconda3\envs\carnd-term1\lib\site-packages\dns\name.py", line 852, in from_unicode
    raise EmptyLabel
dns.name.EmptyLabel: A DNS label is empty.
```

This is my host file:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

Comment: What is you `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: Hello I edited my question to include the host file I think. I am not an expert of this matter and I just looked up how to do it on google

Comment: Could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69145612/372643