# The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted: Not getting solution

Tags: python, windows, pgadmin-4

BELOW ARE THE LOGS:-

### pgAdmin Runtime Environment

```
Python Path: "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\python.exe"
Runtime Config File: "C:\Users\USERS\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\python.exe -s C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgAdmin4.py"
```

Environment:

- ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
- APPDATA: C:\Users\USERS\AppData\Roaming
- ChocolateyInstall: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey
- ChocolateyLastPathUpdate: 132359073976999036
- CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \.\pipe\crashpad_54000_XEIJHGSOHGBAUUBQ
- CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|Whoa! NW.js has crashed. Relaunch now?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
- CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
- CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
- CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
- COMPUTERNAME: DESKTOP-08HN5NH
- ComSpec: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
- DriverData: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
- ERLANG_HOME: C:\Program Files\erl9.3
- HOMEDRIVE: C:
- HOMEPATH: \Users\USERS
- LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\USERS\AppData\Local
- LOGONSERVER: \DESKTOP-08HN5NH
- NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 4
- OneDrive: C:\Users\USERS\OneDrive
- OS: Windows_NT
- Path:

```
C:\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Python310\;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\elastic_stack\elasticsearch-7.9.2\bin;C:\webdriver;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin;C:\Users\USERS\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\USERS\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\USERS\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.3\bin;C:\Users\USERS\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

- PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW
- PGADMIN_INT_KEY: 536647b0-6442-47dd-ba86-930c7b68af6c
- PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 51672
- PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
- PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
- PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
- PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
- PROCESSOR_REVISION: 8e09
- ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
- ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
- ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
- ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
- PSModulePath: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\PowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
- PT7HOME: C:\Program Files\Cisco Packet Tracer 7.3.1
- PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
- QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO: auto
- SystemDrive: C:
- SystemRoot: C:\WINDOWS
- TEMP: C:\Users\OMPRAK~1\AppData\Local\Temp
- TMP: C:\Users\OMPRAK~1\AppData\Local\Temp
- USERDOMAIN: DESKTOP-08HN5NH
- USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: DESKTOP-08HN5NH
- USERNAME: USERS
- USERPROFILE: C:\Users\USERS
- VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
- windir: C:\WINDOWS
- __COMPAT_LAYER: DetectorsAppHealth

```
--------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 39, in <module>
    import config
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\config.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pgadmin.utils import env, IS_WIN, fs_short_path
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from socketio import socketio_manage  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\socketio\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .zmq_manager import ZmqManager
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\socketio\zmq_manager.py", line 5, in <module>
    import eventlet.green.zmq as zmq
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\eventlet\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from eventlet import convenience
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\eventlet\convenience.py", line 7, in <module>
    from eventlet.green import socket
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\eventlet\green\socket.py", line 21, in <module>
    from eventlet.support import greendns
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\eventlet\support\greendns.py", line 401, in <module>
    resolver = ResolverProxy(hosts_resolver=HostsResolver())
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\eventlet\support\greendns.py", line 315, in __init__
    self.clear()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\eventlet\support\greendns.py", line 318, in clear
    self._resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver(filename=self._filename)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 543, in __init__
    self.read_registry()
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 720, in read_registry
    self._config_win32_fromkey(key, False)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 674, in _config_win32_fromkey
    self._config_win32_domain(dom)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 639, in _config_win32_domain
    self.domain = dns.name.from_text(str(domain))
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\dns\name.py", line 889, in from_text
    return from_unicode(text, origin, idna_codec)
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\lib\site-packages\dns\name.py", line 852, in from_unicode
    raise EmptyLabel
dns.name.EmptyLabel: A DNS label is empty.
```

I have tried al the thing which has been given in the below link but still i am geeting this error

[pgadmin4 : postgresql application server could not be contacted.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211296/pgadmin4-postgresql-application-server-could-not-be-contacted)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted: Fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68862998/the-pgadmin-4-server-could-not-be-contacted-fatal-error)

Comment: The error message `A DNS label is empty.` is defined In `"C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\Lib\site-packages\dns\name.py"` . I think someone with enough python knowledge might now the answer.